# How to use injected service from razor layout view in child view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, dependency-injection

Just learning about [injected services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1) in asp.net core razor views. But I haven't been able to find out how to use a service that is injected in the layout view (will be used by many views), in child views.

Maybe something conceptually like this:

**Layout View**

```
@inject IOptions<PortalConfiguration> OptionsPortalConfiguration

<some HTLM markup>
@RenderBody(OptionsPortalConfiguration) <--pass it here???
```

**Child View**

```
Not sure how to reference it.
```

Comment: Have you tried adding @inject IOp... to the concrete view (the one you gonna render at body) ?

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but doesn't seem DRY. If it is already injected at the parent level, seems like extra overhead to inject it again at the child level.

Comment: I don't consider it as a violation if you truly needs in the wrapper level as well. And i don't consider them as parent-children relationship as well, due the fact that the "Body View" doesn't know who render it. thus you shouldn't relay on it to have the injected service as well. Also, further consider if you truly needs the wrapper view to hold the injected service on the first place.

Comment: you are right. It doesn't seem DRY. Did you by any chance get an answer to this one?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach for that kind of situations would be to create static helper methods, which can be called in all views without injection.

```
public static class TestHelperExtensions
{
    public static ITestProvider TestProvider { get; set; }

    public static string Get(this ITestHelper html, string arg)
    {
        return TestProvider.Get(arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to grab the settings from appSettings and pass it back with this method. I don't think I can use DI with static classes.